# Images that I create in Gimp when pasted into Gimp show up translucent

Tags: gimp

I created curved text on a transparent image using TEXT ALONG PATH and PATH TO SELECTION. I filled the text with background color BLACK. The resulting image was curved black text.  When I tried to copy and paste the curved black text it pastes translucent and appears to be selected but nothing can be done to it.  I tried exporting the image as a .png (exported image worked wonderfully in Word and Powerpoint) and then opening it in Gimp to copy and paste onto another image but the exact thing happens.  Even when I take the exported .png into another program and saving it as a .jpg, when opened in Gimp the text was translucent.  Help!

Comment: Screenshot of the GIMP ui (image and Layers list)? Do you see the curved text in one of the layer thumbnails in the Layers list?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post. I would have left a comment instead but I don't have enough points.

After copying and pasting, create a new layer so that what you pasted would be in a layer of it's own.

Simply copying and pasting would make a floating selection (I think that was what it was called. Can't remember the exact term).

I hope this helps someone.